# unable install occlum in ubuntu20.04

Tags: permissions, git, make

```
intel@intel-M50CYP2SBSTD:~/akarsh/occlum$ make submodule
```

Add Git hooks that check Rust code format issues before commits and pushes

```
git submodule init
git submodule update  --progress

cd deps/serde-json-sgx && git apply ../serde-json-sgx.patch 
>/dev/null 2>&1 || git apply ../serde-json-sgx.patch -R --check

cd deps/ringbuf && git apply ../ringbuf.patch >/dev/null 2>&1 || git apply ../ringbuf.patch -R --check

cd deps/resolv-conf && git apply ../resolv-conf.patch >/dev/null 2>&1 || git apply ../resolv-conf.patch -R --check

rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/src/libos/src_sim/process/task': 

Permission denied

rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/src/libos/src_sim/process/do_spawn': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/src/libos/src_sim/util': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/src/libos/src_sim/syscall': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/src/libos/cargo-target': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/src/libos/lib': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/tools/protect-integrity/App/Enclave_u.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/tools/protect-integrity/App/Enclave_u.c': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/tools/protect-integrity/App/App.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/tools/protect-integrity/App/Enclave_u.h': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/internal/tools/protect-integrity/Enclave': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/bin/occlum': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/bin/occlum_build.mk': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/lib': Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:33: submodule] Error 1
```

Comment: Where is the command that produced this output?

Comment: "make submodule" Please try: `sudo make submodule` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting